# How to make a snap program use the same ~/.config, dconf as my apt programs?

Tags: snap

I installed `remmina` via `snap`. It works great.

Only issue is, it doesn't seem to be picking up `~/.config/remmina` where my remotes are stored, or the `dconf` setting `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme` where my desktop theme is stored.

How can I make `snap` `remmina` use the same settings as `apt` `remmina`?